# Setting up wireless access point to differentiate between inside and outside devices?

Tags: wireless-networking

I need to devise a Wi-Fi system that can differentiate between systems that are inside the house and others that are outside the house. A person gains entry to the house if his device's MAC address matches with the previously saved ones. So the door should not open for people who are already inside the house but should open for those outside. How can I differentiate between the two? Because both kinds of devices are in contact with the same Wi-Fi, their probe requests will all be sent to the same router.

Comment: MACs are easily spoofed, so this is a poor choice of security.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know too much about your system and what you are trying to achieve.  But I would configure 2 SSIDs, one on the AP outside and 1 on the AP inside.  If your AP had the capability of turning down the RF power, do so for the inside AP.  Although, that get a bit tricky, because you may lose connectivity around the perimeter inside your house.  If you don't want to configure two different SSID's, then lowering the power on both devices, so that they do not overlap, is your best option.

Comment: I did't understand what lowering the power exactly means. Can you please share some more details regarding that.

Comment: Sure @ShivamAgrawal - Some Access Points give you the ability to lower the RF (radio frequency) output power.  The lower the RF power, the less wireless coverage you have.  If your Access Point vendor allows you to lower the RF power, then that would be the best way to separate your two locations.

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to do this.

The obvious answer is to turn your house into a Faraday cage, and have an AP inside and outside.  (By Faraday cage I mean something where the external walls and Windows don't leak WIFI signals - and - of-course, you need to handle the case of when the door is actually opened - but I assume that can be done in code).    the issue is that preventing WIFI leakage out your house is probably going to mean expensive and exotic building materials.

You might be able to get a part way there by having low powered WIFI AP's in each room (or, preferably WIFI AP's where you can adjust the signal), ad a higher power one outside.   by having low powered AP's the signal is not going to go as far, and you can get a better idea where people are.  Its not fullproof though.

Depending on your exact use case, a hybrid solution might work - where you have a WIFI AP outside the main door, and another inside it, with a grounded metal door between them, and grounded mesh on the outside of the house.  This could create an affect of allowing an approach from outside to connect to the stronger outside signal, and similarly with the indoor one.

That said, maybe this is the wrong tool for the job - Have you considered using NFC (Near field communication) which is built into most cellphones.  These have a way smaller transmitter range (cm's to meters typically) - so having an NFC transceiver outside the door would probably do it - effectively turning the cellphones into a sort-of "Prox Card" - and for devices which don't have NFC, you can buy tags dirt cheap and stick it on them, or even use things like RFID enabled credit cards.